How to set up an authorization token in a pipeline (such as Azure DevOps, GitLab or GitHub actions)?
I'm struggling to get this to work. I need to store the authorization URL for the orgs in the pipeline tool's secret store, but I can't seem to figure how to use it properly in the script itself to authorize the environment and perform the commands.
What I tried so far was to get the authorization URL with the org display command, and saving it to a file:
$ sf org display -o myorgalias --verbose --json | jq .result.sfdxAuthUrl > authurl

But then, when I try to use that file to authorize the org, it fails:
$ echo authurl | sf org login sfdx-url -a playground --sfdx-url-stdin


Error (1): Invalid SFDX auth URL. Must be in the format "force://::@".  Note that the SFDX auth URL uses the "force" protocol, and not "http" or "https".  Also note that the "instanceUrl" inside the SFDX auth URL doesn't include the protocol ("https://").


1. The jq command should use the raw flag (-r) so its output does not contain double quotes.
sf org display -o playground --verbose --json | jq -r .result.sfdxAuthUrl > authurl

Then the result file contains a line that starts with force://... instead of "force://....
2. The authorization command should use cat instead of echo
echo would just output the file name (authurl in this case, which obviously isn't an authorization URL). But cat outputs the file's contents, which is what we want.
$ cat authurl | sf org login sfdx-url -a playground --sfdx-url-stdin


Successfully authorized renato@theorg.com with org ID 00D...

